# get first row given by a column value in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am a newbie to pandas, maybe this is a simple problem, but i can't catch it after searching a lot on google. How can I get the first row given by a column value?

For example, I have the dataframe bellow:

```
>>> df

0  1
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  2
```

I want to get the first row where `2` appears, in this example the row is:

```
>>> df
3  2
```

Note that there is no column name in the dataframe. So, how can I get that? I would appreciate it very much if anyone can provide any help.

Comment: Firstly you can do `df[df==2].iloc[0]` secondly, is this really a dataframe? it maybe a Series

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. And it is a Series, because I cut it from a dataframe, this makes me think it is a dataframe. Thank you! @EdChum

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a `Series` because you mentioned that you have no column name.

Anyway you can use a boolean mask to mask the `Series` and then use `iloc` to give you the first row:

```
df[df==2].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answer from 2021, I was having the same problem and figured out myself:

```
(df == 2) ## will give you a panda DF of T/F dataframe
(df == 2).iloc[:, 0] ## will select the first row of this T/F dataframe
((df == 2).iloc[:, 0]).idxmax() ## will return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis
```

In my case, it was working as this. You may change the `idxmax()` into (example can be `index[0]`) the function you need to extract your index from pandas.